# Prevent existing execution due to obtaining "NaN" result from Gnuplot's fit command

Tags: gnuplot, nan

My `gnuplot` script contains series of fitting:

```
...
fit f(x) "$data" via a, r
...
fit f(x) "$data" via a, r
...
fit f(x) "$data" via a, r
...
```

which I wish it to run till the end of the script but sometimes, when the `fit` command return `"NaN"` result with error message:

```
Function evaluation yields NaN ("not a number")
```

The program will be dead and the rest of lines will never be executed. My question is how to handle this problem nicely?

Answer (score 0):

There is not yet an option in gp to keep a script running after an error like this. https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/feature-requests/382/

What you can do is pipe your script into gnuplot via STDIN. Then it simply doesn't matter.

```
cat test.gp | gnuplot
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem trying to fit `f(x) = a*exp(b*x)+c`.

I solved it by asigning initial values to variables a,b and c. (1,1,0).